# Is it possible to change a user's password in the front-end?

Tags: templating, form, password, frontend

Is it currently possible to change a user's password in for example the profile edit form? I'm currently using the forgot password approach for this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is! To do so, they will have to be logged in and input their old password. They need the old password to change their email or update a password.

Here's an example:

```html
{% macro errorList(errors) %}
    {% if errors %}
        {% for error in errors %}
            <div class="error icon-cancel-circled">{{ error }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
{% from _self import errorList %}

<form method="post" action="" id="action-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }} {# Remove this if you aren't using CSRF #}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser"> {# "users/save-user" if you're on Craft 3 #}
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ entry.url }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">

    <label for="currentPassword">Current Password</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="currentPassword" name="password" />
    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('currentPassword')) }}
    {% endif %}

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="text" />
    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('email')) }}
    {% endif %}

    <label for="newPassword">New Password</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newPassword" name="newPassword" />
    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('newPassword')) }}
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

This is code that would be inserted into a new custom front end template.

Comment: Isn't this missing a submit button?

Comment: And does this still work for Craft 3.5? Thanks!