# frontend account edits

Tags: craft3, users, frontend-form

I have an account page for all my users, however i'm running into a small issue with being able to update passwords / emails on the frontend. Any advice on how to do this? I read that updating either of those fields would require checking and verifying the change in your email.

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind using PHP?

Comment: I don't mind using PHP, craft just has terrible documentation and almost every article i find is using craft v2.

Answer (score 2):

A user changing sensitive fields like passwords and email addresses requires a "elevated session" to do so, which requires them to enter their *current* password.

You can see the template code to do that here for both Craft 2 and 3: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4715/57

You can configure the duration of the elevated session with the [elevatedSessionDuration](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#elevatedsessionduration) config setting.

Comment: So i tried the above, and no luck, It will update my password but not my email,

Comment: Guessing you've got user email validation enabled. If your email settings are setup correctly an email should get sent to the new email address. Once that is clicked, the email address will change for the user.

Comment: I set up the form as shown in the link you sent, changed the email and nothing happens. i receive no email regarding the change. What email settings should be modified ?

Comment: Under Settings->Email in the Control Panel.  See https://craftcms.com/support/why-doesnt-craft-send-emails and https://craftcms.com/support/troubleshooting-email-errors#dealing-with-email-delivery-issues